# Azure Linux VM and BitBucket

Tags: azure, bitbucket, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure Linux VM, and a BitBucket repository.
I would like to setup continuous development between the two, however all the tutorials I could find are for Azure Web Apps, and not for Linux VM.

Comment: what are you trying to deploy ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in SCM integration with Virtual Machines; it's only built-in for Web Apps.

You'll need to set up / configure your own deployment scheme, to pull your deployments from BitBucket into your VM. How you do that is quite a broad and opinion-soliciting topic / discussion, and out of scope for StackOverflow.